# Get repository link from gem?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

Is it possible to get the git repository of a gem?

Eg the gem thor has repo of http://github.com/wycats/thor.git

Could I get this repo link from the thor gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, gems do not store any information about where their active development is located. Some gems do have a home page declared, but that is not necessarily their git repository (not everyone uses Github). Everything that Rubygems knows about the gem is in its gemspec ([which you can view on Github](http://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/master/thor.gemspec)).

Comment: You can also view any gem's spec, whether it's installed or not, with the gem spec command.  For example, gem spec --remote thor

Comment: Yep - I mentioned the spec only to demonstrate that the information desired wasn't present.